# magento 1.5.0.1 upload image button doesn't display

Tags: product-images, catalog, magento-1.5.1

I am using magento 1.5.0.1
[image]

My problem is i want to upload an image,but upload image and browse image buttons are not displaying.

Comment: Your browser has flash player working correctly? can you try it on other browser?

Comment: already tried but not working

Comment: https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader - Use this for alternative. It not require flash for upload image

Comment: Also see console for error

Comment: is it work for you?